# Groovy Metaprogramming - Where shall I put it?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I am writing a small Groovy libaray with some packages and some classes. For one of them, I would like to tweak the `asType` method of `Map`, so what I can write something like this:

```
import cm.ConfigMap

oldimpl = Map.metaClass.getMetaMethod("asType", [Class] as Class[])

Map.metaClass.asType = { Class c ->
    if (c == ConfigMap) {
        new ConfigMap(rootMap: delegate)
    } else {
        oldimpl.invoke(delegate, c)
    }
}

Map m = [ "key" : "value",
          "a"   : "z" ]

ConfigMap config = m as ConfigMap
```

This works as expected in a Groovy script, but I don't know there I can the put MOP instructions if I would like to use it my library and not in a script, so that my implementation of `asType` can be used everythere where my libary is used too.

Comment: Have you tried http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#module-descriptor ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution, using a module descriptor, which allows to create an instance of my custom class `ConfigMap` out of a normal map via the `as` operator.
allows to cast a map via `as` to my custom class `ConfigMap`.

Since each Groovy map in Groovy 2.5 is an instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap`, it is needed to provide an enhanced variant of `asType(...)` as extension method for the `LinkedHashMap`:

```
package cm

class LinkedHashMapExtension {
    static def asType(LinkedHashMap self, Class clazz) {
        def oldAsType = LinkedHashMap.metaClass.getMetaMethod("asType", 
                                                              [Class] as Class[])

        if (clazz == ConfigMap) {
            return new ConfigMap(rootMap: self)
        }

        return oldAsType.invoke(self, clazz)
    }
}
```

To register the class above as extension, a file called `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule` with the following content:

```
moduleName=Test module for specifications
moduleVersion=1.0-test
extensionClasses=cm.LinkedHashMapExtension
```

All needed information can be found at http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#module-descriptor